# Необходимо убрать тень при нажатии

Tags: android, android-studio, button, android-style, android-drawer

[image: Слева небольшая тень]

Использовал следующий код для удаления фона

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/white"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
```

Не могу понять, как убрать тень в статичном режиме и при нажатии

Comment: вы с таким успехом можете использовать не кнопку, а просто TextView. У него и не будет тени

Comment: спасибо большое. что-то я совсем про это забыл

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LolliPop?

В коде:

```
button.setStateListAnimator(null);
```

Или в разметке:

```
<Button
...
android:stateListAnimator="@null" 
....
/>
```